# Tikz : Plot a function inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows

I am using tikz to reproduce a Matlab picturization of a neural network. The original figure that I need to reproduce is this :

[image]

I am stuck at plotting the tanh function and the linear function inside the node.
I have tried two methods as of now : pgfplots and tikz plot function but I am unable to move the plot inside the rectangle.

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{bg_deepred}{RGB}{150,0,24}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [grid/.style={very thin,gray},
    conn/.style={->,blue,very thick},
    inp/.style={opacity=.5,very thick,black,fill=red},
    oup/.style={opacity=.5,very thick,black,fill=blue},
    int/.style={opacity=.5,very thick,black,fill=gray},
    int1/.style={opacity=.5, thick, black, fill=yellow},
    plane/.style={opacity=.6,draw=none,fill=yellow!80!black},
    line/.style={very thick}]

    % input layer
    \draw[inp,rounded corners] (-1, 2.5) rectangle (1, -3.8) {};

    % scalar values (only internal circles)
    \shade[ball color=green] (0,.5) circle (.5cm);
    \draw (0,0.5) node[scale=2]{2};
    \shade[ball color=green] (0,1.7) circle (.5cm);
    \draw (0,1.7) node[scale=2]{1};

    \draw (0,-0.4) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](a){};
    \draw (0,-0.7) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](b){};
    \draw (0,-1.0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](c){};


    \shade[ball color=green] (0,-1.8) circle (.5cm);
    \draw (0,-1.8) node[scale=2]{26};
    \shade[ball color=green] (0,-3) circle (.5cm);
    \draw (0,-3) node[scale=2]{27};
    %\draw [fill=bg_deepred](0,\y) circle (2.5mm);

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % input layer
    \draw[int,rounded corners] (3, 2) rectangle (8, -3) {};

    \draw[int1] (3.5, 1.5) rectangle (5, 0) {};
    \draw[int1] (3.5, -1) rectangle (5, -2.5) {};

    \draw[int1] (6.0, 1.5) rectangle (7.5, -2.5) {};

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % output layer
    \draw[int,rounded corners] (10, 2) rectangle (15, -3) {};

    \draw[int1] (10.5, 1.5) rectangle (12, 0) {};
    \draw[int1] (10.5, -1) rectangle (12, -2.5) {};
    \draw[int1] (13.0, 1.5) rectangle (14.5, -2.5) {};

    %tikz version not working
    \begin{scope}[x=1pt,y=10pt,shift={(100,0)}]
      \draw (5,5) plot[domain=-8:8] (\x,{1/(1 + exp(-\x))-0.5});
    \end{scope}

    %pgfplots version not working
    \begin{axis}[width=5.5cm,height=4cm,ymin=-1.25,ymax=1.25,xmin=-5,xmax=5]
    \addplot[blue,smooth] {tanh(x)};
    \end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the followin with the blue curve provided using pgfplots package and the black one provided by the tikzplot package.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

You have to adjust the `shift` of `scope` so that its placed at the middle of node. Then just scale to required value.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [grid/.style={very thin,gray},
    conn/.style={->,blue,very thick},
    inp/.style={opacity=.5,very thick,black,fill=red},
    oup/.style={opacity=.5,very thick,black,fill=blue},
    int/.style={opacity=.5,very thick,black,fill=gray},
    int1/.style={opacity=.5, thick, black, fill=yellow},
    plane/.style={opacity=.6,draw=none,fill=yellow!80!black},
    line/.style={very thick}]

    % input layer
    \draw[inp,rounded corners] (-1, 2.5) rectangle (1, -3.8) {};

    % scalar values (only internal circles)
    \shade[ball color=green] (0,.5) circle (.5cm);
    \draw (0,0.5) node[scale=2]{2};
    \shade[ball color=green] (0,1.7) circle (.5cm);
    \draw (0,1.7) node[scale=2]{1};

    \draw (0,-0.4) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](a){};
    \draw (0,-0.7) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](b){};
    \draw (0,-1.0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](c){};

    \shade[ball color=green] (0,-1.8) circle (.5cm);
    \draw (0,-1.8) node[scale=2]{26};
    \shade[ball color=green] (0,-3) circle (.5cm);
    \draw (0,-3) node[scale=2]{27};
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % input layer
    \draw[int,rounded corners] (3, 2) rectangle (8, -3) {};
    \draw[int1] (3.5, 1.5) rectangle (5, 0) {};
    \draw[int1] (3.5, -1) rectangle (5, -2.5) {};
    \draw[int1] (6.0, 1.5) rectangle (7.5, -2.5) {};
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % output layer
    \draw[int,rounded corners] (10, 2) rectangle (15, -3) {};  
    \draw[int1] (10.5, 1.5) rectangle (12, 0) {};
    \draw[int1] (10.5, -1) rectangle (12, -2.5) {};
    \draw[int1] (13.0, 1.5) rectangle (14.5, -2.5) {};

    %tikz version working
    \begin{scope}[x=2pt,y=2cm,shift={(6.75cm,-0.5cm)}]
      \draw[gray!50,thick] (-8,0) -- (8,0);
      \draw[gray!50,thick] (0,-1cm) -- (0,1cm);
      \draw[thick] (0,0) plot[domain=-8:8] (\x,{1/(1 + exp(-\x))-0.5});
    \end{scope}

    %tikz version working
    \begin{scope}[x=2pt,y=2cm,shift={(13.75cm,-0.5cm)}]
      \draw[gray!50,thick] (-8,0) -- (8,0);
      \draw[gray!50,thick] (0,-1cm) -- (0,1cm);
      \draw[thick] (-8,-1cm)--(8,1cm);
    \end{scope}    
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: fabulous .. i was playing with but it wasnt working as I wished. Any pointers as to how to put on those arrows (i will try the default version)

Comment: i was missing the cm in the shift ... oops :)

Comment: @datapanda arrows can be drawn easily. You can find examples here and in http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ .

Comment: what if i have to make the function of qual aspect ratio, right now it looks the height is more than the breadth.

Comment: @datapanda Change the `y=2cm` value in the `scope`.

Answer (score 2):

an alternative approach:

- use of small pictures `pic` for nodes symbols
- symbols are not needed to be drawn with plot function, it is sufficient to approximate it with `controls` macro
- used are relative coordinates
- shown are only hidden and output node

  ```
  \documentclass[tikz,margin=3.141529mm]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, backgrounds, calc, fit, positioning}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance = 4mm and 4mm,
      arr/.style = {semithick, -{Triangle[width=3pt,length=3pt]}, rounded corners},
      box/.style = {draw, semithick, fill=yellow!40,
                    minimum size=6mm, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm},
     circ/.style = {circle, draw,fill=white, inner sep=0.5mm, outer sep=0mm,
                    node contents={}},
      FIT/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, rounded corners, inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm,
                    fit=#1, node contents={}},
      sum/.style = {circle, draw, fill=yellow!40, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
                    font=\large, node contents={+}},
        lin/.pic = {\draw[very thin]  (-0.4,0) -- ++ (0.8,0)
                                      (0,-0.5) -- ++ (0,1.0);
                    \draw[semithick]  (-0.4,-0.4) -- (0.4,0.4);
                      },
        sat/.pic = {\draw[very thin]  (-0.4,0) -- ++ (0.8,0)
                                      (0,-0.5) -- ++ (0,1.0);
                    \draw[semithick]
                      (-0.4,-0.4) .. controls + (2mm,0mm) and + (-2mm,-4mm) .. (0,0)
                                  .. controls + (2mm,4mm) and + (-2mm, 0mm) .. (0.4,0.4);
                      },
                          ]
  % hidden node
  \node (a1)  [box] {$W$};
  \node (a2)  [box, below=of a1]  {b};
  \node (a3)  [sum, right=of $(a1.east)!0.5!(a2.east)$];
  \path   let \p1 = ($(a1.north)-(a2.south)$),
              \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
          node (a4) [box, minimum height=\n1,
                     right=of a3] {};
  \pic[scale=0.5] at (a4.center) {sat};
      \draw[arr] (a1) -| (a3);
      \draw[arr] (a3) edge (a4) (a2) -| (a3);
  \scoped[on background layer]
      \node (a5)  [FIT=(a1) (a4)];
  \node (a6) [circ,at=(a5.west |- a1)];
  \draw[arr] (a6) -- (a1);
  % output node
      \begin{scope}[xshift=33mm]
  \node (b1)  [box] {$W$};
  \node (b2)  [box, below = of b1]  {b};
  \node (b3)  [sum, right=of $(b1.east)!0.5!(b2.east)$];
  \path   let \p1 = ($(b1.north)-(b2.south)$),
              \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
          node (b4) [box, minimum height=\n1,
                     right=of b3] {};
  \pic[scale=0.5] at (b4.center) {lin};
      \draw[arr] (b1) -| (b3);
      \draw[arr] (b3) edge (b4) (b2) -| (b3);
  \scoped[on background layer]
      \node (b5)  [FIT=(b1) (b4)];
  \node (b6) [circ,at=(b5.west |- a1)];
  \draw[arr] (b6) -- (b1);
      \end{scope}
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]